# How to properly set encoding for files, databases, connections, etc.?

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I am migrating a mysql database from one site to another.

Its encodign: utf8

Its connection encodign: utf8_unicode_ci

The encoding used in the php files of that site: utf-8 without BOM

The encoding in the headers for every page in that site: utf-8

Everything works fine in that site.

Then I exported the database using phpmyadmin.
It generated a .sql file, encoded with utf-8, and when I open it everything is fine.

Then I copied that file to the new site, which uses the same encoding for everything, and imported it.

When I show the data from the old site, in the new one, through a web page, it shows broken characters. Eg: ™ => �.

If I turn the encoding of the browser from utf-8 to iso-8859-1, I see the correct symbol.

Everything else in the new site works fine, I have no encoding problems after saving stuff to the database and pulling it back. The only strange thing is that when I browse the data stored, phpmyadmin shows broken chars. But I don't have that problem when showing the content in the website.

I did the import with two different programs: phpmyadmin and webmin.

So I have no clue about what is wrong here, any thoughts?

How should I have configured the encodings so this didn't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe in the first site you didn't set the connection encoding (see output of mysql_client_encoding() in php ).
If that is the problem you stored your data in the wrong format, and you were also converting it back correctly using the same misbehaviour.

p.s. utf8_unicode_ci is not an encoding, is a collation (how to order your strings)

Comment: Wow, you are a genius. The connection in the old site was in 'latin1'. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty good [FAQ on charsets and encodings in PHP](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/php_charset_encoding_FAQ.html).

Answer (score 0):

This happened me before with an old site, it was in a different collation, so once you tried to change it to utf8 it shows strange symbols all over.

Sometimes the backend in phpmyadmin shows the strange codes, but the site shows alright.